# Overlap two bars in BarGraph MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I've got to draw bars overlapping each other on same x-Axis. I have checked multiple answers on stackoverflow and google but not found the solution. Is this possible to draw bars like in image below using MPAndroidChart?[image]

What currently I am  having is this.
[image]

Here is my code.`

```
private fun barChart2() {
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.setDrawBarShadow(false)
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.setDrawValueAboveBar(true)
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.setMaxVisibleValueCount(50)
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.setPinchZoom(false)
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.setDrawGridBackground(false)
        val xl: XAxis = binding.barChartRevenueEarning.xAxis
        xl.granularity = 1f
        xl.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
        xl.setValueFormatter(object : ValueFormatter() {
            override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String? {
                return value.toString()
            }

            val decimalDigits: Int
                get() = 0
        })

        val leftAxis: YAxis = binding.barChartRevenueEarning.getAxisLeft()
        leftAxis.setValueFormatter(object : ValueFormatter() {
            override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String? {
                return value.toString()
            }

            val decimalDigits: Int
                get() = 0
        })
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        leftAxis.spaceTop = 30f
        leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f)

        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false)
        val groupSpace = 0.04f
        val barSpace = 0f
        val barWidth = 0.46f
        val startYear = 1980f
        val endYear = 1985
        val dataSet1: MutableList<BarEntry> = ArrayList()
        val dataSet2: MutableList<BarEntry> = ArrayList()

        for (i in 1..15) {
            dataSet1.add(BarEntry(i.toFloat(), 0.4f))
            dataSet2.add(BarEntry((i).toFloat(), 0.7f))
        }

        val set1: BarDataSet
        val set2: BarDataSet
        set1 = BarDataSet(dataSet1, "Company A")
        set1.color = Color.rgb(104, 241, 175)
        set2 = BarDataSet(dataSet2, "Company B")
        set2.color = Color.rgb(164, 228, 251)
        val barData = BarData()
        barData.addDataSet(set1)
        barData.addDataSet(set2)
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.data = barData
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.barData.barWidth = barWidth
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.groupBars(-1f, groupSpace, barSpace)
        binding.barChartRevenueEarning.invalidate()
    }
```

`

Comment: check if we can set custom drawable  bars ?

Comment: yes, I am trying.